# How does D solve this issue with return types?

Tags: function, syntax, d

C++11 introduced a new syntax for function declaration,

```
auto func(T rhs, U lhs) -> V
```

This was to solve some problems that appeared in the old C++ standard with function templates. Read this short Wikipedia article section for details about the problem:
> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Alternative_function_syntax

My question is, does D confront with the same problem? If so, how does it fix it (if at all)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In D, the compiler can deduce the return type for you. So there's no need to have the `-> V`  syntax.

```
auto func(T, U)(T lhs, U rhs) { return lhs + rhs; }
```

or if you want to be more specific (but it's better to let the compiler figure out the type with `auto`!)

```
typeof(T.init + U.init) func(T, U)(T lhs, U rhs) { return lhs + rhs; }
```

Like C++, you cannot use `typeof(lhs + rhs)` in that place.

Comment: How does it handle cases with multiple return statements? (I guess it issues an error if they are of different types. :-) )

Comment: @PaulManta: Currently, the return type will be set to the type of the first `return` statement encountered. Then all other `return` statements have to be the same type of that. If some `return` statments have a different type DMD-FE will raise a "mismatched function return type inference" error.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure, but I believe you can use the `typeof(<expression>)` syntax. So it should be possible to do something like: `typeof(rhs+lhs) func(T rhs, U lhs) { /* body */ }`

Comment: So D parses the argument list before the return type?

Comment: @Paul Manta The order of declarations doesn't generally matter in D (aside from within function bodies, of course). Obviously, the compiler parses from left-to-right, but the semantic analysis of declarations is done later, so the fact that `typeof(rhs+lhs)` comes before either `rhs` or `lhs` is declared is of no consequence.

Comment: As KennyTM pointed out in his answer, you can't do `typeof(rhs + lhs)` but you can do `typeof(T.init + U.init)`.

Comment: Yep, it was a quick edit. As I wrote, I was not 100% sure. :) So yes, `typeof(T.init + U.init) fun(T l, U r) {}` is the good way.